# Como obrigar o Highcharts a mostrar todos os pontos?

Tags: javascript, html, css, highcharts, gráfico

Utilizo a API do **highcharts** para gerar gráficos a partir de informações coletadas em uma base de dados, o problema é que quando vem muitos pontos na sua série, ele OCULTA e GERA uma Média em períodos..

Veja o exemplo nesse [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/58y099Ln/3/). O ponto maior mostrado é de **6.888**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porem isso é a média das coletas feitas em **6:00 (4.62), 6:05 (9.14) e 6:10 (5.13)** fazendo a média da **(6.88)**. O problema é que ao fazer uma analise você não consegue saber até qual ponto chegou a menos que de zoom. veja:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu não quero que ele mostre média! Quero que mostre ponto a ponto, como devo configurar meu gráfico? Já procurei na documentação mas não encontrei nada :/
alguém pode me ajuda?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O highcharts trabalha com o conceito de [agrupamento de dados](https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/plotOptions.series.dataGrouping.approximation) para melhor visualização dos dados.

Ao utilizar o agrupamento, a amostragem é feita por base de possíveis valores, como média ou soma.

Você pode desabilitar o `dataGrouping`, basta adicionar este código:

```
plotOptions: {
      series: {
        dataGrouping: {
          enabled: false
      }
   }
}
```

[Veja o seu exemplo atualizado.](https://jsfiddle.net/58y099Ln/8/)

Desde a versão v4.2.7 você também pode utilizar uma função de *callback* para extrair os dados, [conforme este exemplo.](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/stock/plotoptions/series-datagrouping-approximation)